# Why is Firefox ignoring the manifest?

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to learn PWA development. Done some basic exercises, and they work well on Chrome, but Firefox completely ignores the

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
```

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest it should work, but the manifest is not even requested from the server.

Do you have any recommendations on checking what may I be forgiving or doing wrong?

Comment: As an experiment, have you tried putting `manifest.webmanifest` in another folder (ie. not the root folder) and updating the path in your `<link>` to see if the results are any different?

Comment: @rounin Yes, I have tried both on the root folder and on a subfolder. And, just in case, I'm actually trying it now in a real, certified, https server instead of a simple localhost http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web App Manifest is only compatible with Firefox For Android, not Firefox desktop, which makes sense as web app manifests are designed to make a website behave more "app-like".

https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-app-manifest

They *are* supported by Chrome desktop for whatever reason, which is why you are seeing your server hit by Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @Maximillian I see it's as you say, though I don't agree on it making sense. IMHO PWA are/would be as useful in the desktop as in a mobile device.

Comment: @ToniHomedesiSaun Keep in mind that you can use other PWA APIs like service workers. That's enough to get your web app working a lot like an offline app!